# Loading... Forever

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a project where a google sheet calls various google app script custom functions. I've been developing this project for a couple months and everything has been working correctly. However, whenever I hopped on my computer this morning, all the custom functions just said `Loading...`. I've been trying everything and for the life of me, I can't get my sheet to call any custom functions without `Loading...` going on indefinitely. Even if it's a function as simple as:

> function myFunction(){
> return 3;
> }

I still can't get it to work. I've tried refreshing, copying the sheet, changing the name, etc. but I still can't get any custom functions to work. I can call them directly from the code console, and they run as expected, but for the life of me, I can't get them to work by being called from the sheet directly. Does anyone have any ideas/thoughts on this?